# Pagy gem not returning the last page records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
pagy,records = pagy(Products.all,page: params[:page], items: 5 )
```

I have total of 10 records. when I request for page 1 records, I get

```
#<Pagy:0x00007f1dec7cee88 @vars={:size=>[1, 4, 4, 1]}, @count=10, @items=5, @outset=0, @page=1, @last=2, @pages=2, @offset=0, **@from=1, @to=5**, @prev=nil, @next=2>
```

but for page 2, it gives

```
#<Pagy:0x00007faa0c7d0740 @vars={:size=>[1, 4, 4, 1]}, @count=10, @items=0, @outset=0, @page=2, @last=2, @pages=2, @offset=5, **@from=6, @to=5**, @prev=1, @next=nil>
```

may be because of from 6 to 5 its not returning me any records.

can someone help with what am i missing?

Comment: Can you create an actual minimal verifyable example where you create the records and then paginate the records and explain what you expected  and the actual result? The way this question is written we can't actually verify any of the steps and its impossible to answer "what am i missing?" since we don't have a good picture of whats actually going on.  This leads to both wasting both your and our time as the issue is often outside of the question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/.

Comment: Also do not use all the `ruby-on-rails-x` tags. They are meant to provide context that the question is for a specific version of Rails and won't garner more attention.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.Updating the pagy to latest version solved my issue.